# \setlength{\leftskip} fails

Tags: indentation

The Latex code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Beginning

\Large{Title1}

\medskip

\large{\textbf{subtitle1}}
\medskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}
2012\textendash 2015 \quad \quad wp1.1.\\
\quad pos1.1.\\
\quad tsk1.1.
\medskip

2012\textendash 2015 \quad \quad wp1.2.\\
\quad pos1.2.\\
\quad tsk1.2.
\medskip

2012\textendash 2015 \quad \quad wp1.3.\\
\quad pos1.3.\\
\quad tsk1.3.
\medskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}
\medskip

\large{\textbf{subtitle2}}
\medskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}
2010\textendash 2012 \quad wp2\\
\quad pos2\\
\quad tsk2
\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}

End
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Why does indenting fail after subtitle2? Also there is a problem of font size of "End" which should be equal to the font size of "Beginning".

Comment: For the fot size problem, `\Large` is a switch, not a command with an argument. Everything after this command will have the `Large` size, until you change it to (probably) `\normalsize`.

Comment: you are making the entire document `\Large` but also you should _never_ set `\leftskip` directly it is a tex primitive and setting it will break many latex constructs not least all list constructs.   Why are you not using heading commands for the headings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning a new paragraph should solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Beginning

\Large{Title1}

\medskip

\large{\textbf{subtitle1}}
\medskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}
2012\textendash 2015 \quad \quad wp1.1.\\
\quad pos1.1.\\
\quad tsk1.1.
\medskip

2012\textendash 2015 \quad \quad wp1.2.\\
\quad pos1.2.\\
\quad tsk1.2.
\medskip

2012\textendash 2015 \quad \quad wp1.3.\\
\quad pos1.3.\\
\quad tsk1.3.
\medskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}
\medskip

\large{\textbf{subtitle2}}
\medskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}
2010\textendash 2012 \quad wp2\\
\quad pos2\\
\quad tsk2

\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm} %here a new paragraph - PS

End
\end{document}
```

[image]

(And certainly your `\Large` acts globally).

Comment: What did you change? Where did you insert and how the beginning of a new paragraph?

Comment: @Viesturs A new paragraph is obtained by adding a new line before last `\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}`.

Comment: @Viesturs Now it is marked `%here a new paragraph - PS`.

Comment: you left the OPs error that the entire document is `\large`

Answer (score 6):

A syntax such as `\large{word}` will make the entire document `\large` it should be `{\large word}` but explicit size changes and spacing should be avoided wherever possible, and markup should be used that is closer to the intended meaning, headings here.  Also it is not supported to set the `\leftskip` primitive directly in LaTeX, many constructs notably any list environment needs to be able to set this internally and set latex parameters such as `\lineskip` to compatible values at the same time.

I would suggest a markup closer to

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{wp}[subsection]
\renewcommand\thewp{\arabic{subsection}\ifnum\value{wp}>0.\arabic{wp}\fi}

\newcommand\WPsection[1]{%
\refstepcounter{subsection}%
\subsection*{#1}}

\newcommand\SWP[1]{%
\refstepcounter{wp}%
\subsubsection*{#1\qquad wp\thewp}%
}
\newcommand\WP[1]{%
\subsubsection*{#1\qquad wp\thewp}%
}

\newcommand\pos{\par \noindent\hspace{2em}\makebox[2em][l]{pos}\thewp\par}
\newcommand\tsk{\par \noindent\hspace{2em}\makebox[2em][l]{tsk}\thewp\par}
\begin{document}
Beginning

\section*{Title1}



\WPsection{subtitle1}

\SWP{2012--2015}
\pos
\tsk



\SWP{2012--2015}
\pos
\tsk


\SWP{2012--2015}
\pos
\tsk


\WPsection{subtitle2}

\WP{2010-2012}
\pos
\tsk


End
\end{document}
```